# IOS Firebase | Need to load document which could be in one of two collections

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My database is currently organized into two collections: male_users & female_users. When the app is first launched AND the user is already logged in, I attempt to pull their usernode from the database. The problem I am facing is, at this time I don't know whether to search the MALE_COLLECTION or FEMALE_COLLECTION to find the user. What would be the proper way of working around this? Should I use user defaults to save the gender of the last user?

static func fetchUser(withUid uid: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {

```
    COLLECTION_MALE_USERS.document(uid).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        
        if let userNode = snapshot?.data() {
            guard let user = User(with: userNode) else {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to create user")
                return
            }
            completion(user)
        }
        else {
            COLLECTION_FEMALE_USERS.document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
                guard let userNode = snapshot?.data() else {
                    print("DEBUG: No user node found")
                    return
                }
                guard let user = User(with: userNode) else {
                    print("DEBUG: Failed to create user")
                    return
                }
                
                completion(user)
            }
        }

    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: What is the use case for separating users per gender, I mean why not have this as a property for each document in a one collection called `users`?

Comment: Currently I am using geofire in order to query by location when I want to retrieve users. Because of this (please correct me if I am mistaken) I can't do any additional queries on the fields such as by gender, age, etc. unless I do so on the client side. I felt as if it would be more efficient to structure my database by gender to optimize efficiency

Comment: I still don't get the use case, so for example you would need to query all females by location? or all young users by location, and so? I see you still want to search users by uid, so?

Comment: When a user loads the app and logs in, I fetch their data from the database, in order to display their data on the screen. I fetch their data by searching for their uid. Once this happens, I pressent the user with other people queried by location, age, and distance. Let me know if I still did not calrify enough.

Comment: Okay, now you have a use case to get the user profile using the UID. Then, another use case which is to display other users, so one query will be get all users by location, another query will be get users by age, another query is to get users by distance .. I get it right?
Or you need a complex query that get users by location with specific age, close to by some distance?

Comment: From **Example Usage** in [GeoFire github](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#example-usage), it stores its data separately from your collection of users. Let's say you will store users related-location data using GeoFire by each user UID, and keep all other information about users under one collection called `users` .. once you query users by location, you will get bunch of UIDs for nearby users, use these UIDs to match with whatever criteria you have from `users` collection.

Comment: The problem for me is geoFire will return these UID's, but then if I want to do a compound query like you suggest, I would have to query one-by-one for each user which  would be really slow I think, right?

Comment: Firebase is not like RDBMS for example, it has its limitation compared to other databases.
Try to change the way you implement your use case .. or you have to go with Firebase the hard way (costly too) .. sometimes it helps when you look at your problem from different angle.
Maybe Firebase doesn't fit your use cases at all, understand its power and limitation to make better decisions.

Comment: Your post is more clear in sub comments now, I suggest you explain all you did to me in the post and make it a bit clear the **specific use case** you want.
Because you are working with Firebase, the more complex your queries, the more it gets harder. .. or even impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will make a new post wich will explain my situatuion more clearly. Do you reccomend any other databases I should look into? I have only heard a lot about firebase for IOS development

Comment: If this is for learning purpose, why not give yourself time to experiment different ways to implement the use case, Firebase is still required for iOS projects, but we need to train our brain on fitting the use cases for its powerful and limitation. You will be amazed of how you can achieve a great result with Firebase, it's just a different mindset we are not used to it.

Comment: For different options, I haven't used others yet, why not give a try to services like [Back4App](https://www.back4app.com/), as it claims, it gives you the power of known technologies like REST, GraphQL, RDBMS, NoSQL like MongoDB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like [Ahmed Shendy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4538920/ahmed-shendy) suggested but I'm not familiar with geofire.

You could use something like shown below or better yet, move the second fetch to a new function and call that new function after fetching for male users produces no results.

```
func fetchUser(uid: String, onSuccess: @escaping(_ user: User) -> Void, onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
    
    let maleDocRef = COLLECTION_MALE_USERS.document(uid)
    let femaleDocRef = COLLECTION_FEMALE_USERS.document(uid)

    maleDocRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            onError(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            
            print("male user exists")
            
            guard let data = document.data() else { return }
            let user = User(with: data)
            onSuccess(user)
            
        } else {
            
            print("male user does no exists")
            
            // BOF second fetch
            
            femaleDocRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                
                if let error = error {
                    onError(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                if let document = document, document.exists {
                    print("female user exists")
                    guard let data = document.data() else { return }
                    let user = User(with: data)
                    onSuccess(user)
                    
                } else {
                    print("no user either male or female exist")
                    
                }
            }
            
            // EOF second fetch
            
        }
    }
    
}
```